# MySQL `INNER JOIN` multiples of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Is it possible to `INNER JOIN` a MySQL query to achieve this result?

I have a table with Strategies and a table with Members. The Strategy table holds the ID of the author that corresponds to their ID in the Member table and the ID of an author that updated the existing author's work. Is it possible to grab a reference to both of these people at the same time? Something like the following, which returns no errors, but also no results...

```
SELECT * FROM Strategies 
INNER JOIN Members AS a 
INNER JOIN Members AS b 
WHERE Strategies.ID='2' 
AND Strategies.AuthorID = a.ID 
AND Strategies.UpdateAuthorID = b.ID
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
  s.*,
  a.Name AS MemberName,
  b.Name AS UpdatedMemberName
FROM Strategies  AS s
LEFT JOIN Members AS a ON s.AuthorID = a.ID AND s.ID = 2 
LEFT JOIN Members AS b ON s.UpdateAuthorID = b.ID AND s.ID = 2 ;
```

If you want them in one column use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT 
  s.*,
  COALESCE(a.Name, b.Name) AS MemberName
FROM Strategies  AS s
LEFT JOIN Members AS a ON s.AuthorID = a.ID AND s.ID = 2 
LEFT JOIN Members AS b ON s.UpdateAuthorID = b.ID AND s.ID = 2
```

Comment: I just need to get the values to my php variables so I can display them. So the top one should work right?

Comment: @SnareChops Both will work fine, the first will give you two columns one for `AuthorId` and the other for `UpdatedAuthorId`, but the second query will give you only one column; the one which in non nullable.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT toD.dom_url AS ToURL, 
    fromD.dom_url AS FromUrl, 
    rvw.*

FROM reviews AS rvw

LEFT JOIN domain AS toD 
    ON toD.Dom_ID = rvw.rev_dom_for

LEFT JOIN domain AS fromD 
    ON fromD.Dom_ID = rvw.rev_dom_from
```

if domain is table name